# Which one first, Visual design or icon design?

Tags: mobile

When attempting to build a mobile app and decide its visual design, means colours, shapes, etc, should we design the Icon first which is going to lead the look and feel of the app or should we design the visual for the app first and finally the according icon?

Comment: Whatever works. There are no rules regarding this.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Actually we had this situation already, we asked the icon design first having the idea of the tone and characteristics of the app, but then when trying to fit those colours on the app, we realised that don't behave well on the UI, so that's why it made us feel we made it wrong... wanting to change the icon... We wonder if we just made the icon brief wrongly or we should have done the icon afterwards

Comment: Well, that sounds like your answer then, Franco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really doesn't matter, as there is no right or wrong. It's just a matter of choice. But personally, I think an "icon" should represent the application, not the other way round. So the design of the app should come first.

Comment: Thanks Devrim. I find a bit hard to get a good picture of the mobile app at the very beginning of the project (as we tried and did), and that's the main problem, and maybe it happens mostly for mobile apps, because if we talk about a website, the logo has much more to say than just guide the website style, it represents the company at its all visual representations, unlike an app where I feel it's mainly done to the represent The Mobile App.

Well, that's the experience we had so far. In sum, I'm not really sure yet...